# Return model with nested array between dates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, where-clause

I have the following model that I'd like to retrieve only those values in the List that matches the criteria for a date range.  In my contrived example I'd like to return the job details along with the days that the employee was working at a specific time.

```
public class Job
{
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public List<Day> Days{ get; set; }
}

public class Day
{
    public string DayName { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeEnd { get; set; }
}
```

I populate JobDays via a call to Entity Framework so the Job/Day relationship is established there.

```
IEnumerable<Job> jobDays = DataLayer.MethodCall();
```

The data may look as follows once populated.

```
<Job>
    <JobName>Sweep</JobName>
    <Days> 
        <Day>
          <DayName>Tuesday</DayName>
          <TimeStart>2009-01-06T07:01:00</TimeStart>
          <TimeEnd>2009-01-06T08:00:40</TimeEnd>
        </Day>
        <Day>
          <DayName>Wednesday</DayName>
          <TimeStart>2009-01-07T07:05:00</TimeStart>
          <TimeEnd>2009-01-07T09:01:40</TimeEnd>
        </Day>
        <Day>
          <DayName>Thursday</DayName>
          <TimeStart>2009-01-08T07:05:00</TimeStart>
          <TimeEnd>2009-01-08T08:30:10</TimeEnd>
        </Day>
    </Days>
</Job>
```

I've tried the following but all Day values are still returned.  For the below assume the `Day` class has the `TimeStart` and `TimeEnd` properties.

```
var query = jobDays.Where(d => d.Days.Any(m => m.TimeStart < timeValue && m.TimeEnd > timeValue));
```

How can I return the Job data along with only the matching Day data?

For example, if my .Where() clause were to request the results that occur at `2009-01-06T08:45:00`, I'd like to see all the `<Job>` data but only include the `<Day>` data that matches the date range.

```
<Job>
    <JobName>Sweep</JobName>
    <Days> 
        <Day>
          <DayName>Wednesday</DayName>
          <TimeStart>2009-01-07T07:05:00</TimeStart>
          <TimeEnd>2009-01-07T09:01:40</TimeEnd>
        </Day>
    </Days>
</Job>
```

Currently my process is returning many  elements that do not meet the `.Where()` criteria.

Comment: test my answer and give me a feedback

Comment: I think your mistake is in using `.Any` here.  You are returning all jobDays where any of it's days fall between your range.  Is that what you want?  It would be a lot easier if we saw your model.  It should be something like `var result=db.Days.Where({your criteria}).GroupBy(x=>x.Job);`

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to filter the inner collection of each element in the jobs list. Try `var query = jobDays.Select(j => new Job { JobName = j.JobName, Days = j.Days.Where(m => m.TimeStart < timeValue && m.TimeEnd > timeValue).ToList() }).ToList();`. If you don't want to return jobs with no days, add `.Where(job => job.Days.Count > 0)`

Comment: Since `jobDays` is populated with a data model from my DataLayer I cannot simply do an assignment of the two objects (ie. `Days = j.Days`).  Must I create a modelfactory (or similar) to perform those mappings?

Comment: I apologize.  I had another mapping error that was unrelated.  Your earlier answer has resolved my question.  Can you post it as an answer so I can provide credit?  Thanks!